# Sequence proof Show that if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was wondering if anyone of you could help me with this squence problem.

Show that if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $2$, then the squence $\{ \frac{a_n}{3-a_n} \}$ converge to 2. is the reciprocal valid?

thanks, 
Felipe

so far, I have considered that if the if the lim $a_n$ = 2 ,   then lim {$a_n$} * lim $\{ \frac{1}{3-a_n} \}$ = 2. W
hat do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use the sum, quotient, and product of limits:

{$a_n$} $\to$ 2, then lim (3 - $a_n$) = 1 and lim ($\frac{1}{3-a_n}$) = 1.

Thus lim ($\frac{a_n}{3-a_n}$) = 2.

Otherwise, you can use the fact that |$a_n$-2| $\lt\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon\gt$ 0 and n $\ge$ N for a natural number N determined by  $\epsilon$